# What is loaded into standard namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces

I am currently building my first more complex C++ program that contains an own namespace. Of course, I use several imports. Ehat I found to be strange is that  function included with eg.

```
#include <math.h>
```

can be accessed within the workspace

```
a = cos(b)
```

where the cos function is part of math.h. On the other hand functions included with eg.

```
#include <fstream>
```

must be accesed via

```
std::ifstream
```

or similar. I would like to understand this

Comment: I agree with the answer. Note that, if you 'can't live with this', you might say `namespace math { #include <math.h> }`. This works with C headers, usually doesn't with C++ ones.

Comment: I agree with the duplicate one. I wasn't aware of this c prefix .h thing so I havent searched for it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ standard library includes most of the C library (there are some hazy details around optional parts of the C library).

Since C has no concept of namespacing, everything included from the C library will be in the global namespace. Since `<math.h>` is a C header, its functions are put into global namespace.

Everything included from the C++ standard library will be in the `std::` namespace, like `std::ifstream` when you included `<fstream>` header.

Where it gets fun, are aliases. As an example, `<math.h>` can also be included as `<cmath>`. The idea behind this was that you select whether you want the C symbols in global namespace (including `<math.h>`) or in the `std::` namespace (including `<cmath>`), but this didn't work out and generally if you include the C++ version of the header (ie `<cmath>`), you will get both.

Generally, if a header can either be included via `<foo.h>` or via `<cfoo>`, its a C header. C++ standard library headers do not have these aliases (except when you have to deal with non-standard things like `iostream.h` that apparently still exist on some platforms).